# How to get all messages of an Inbox in django?

Tags: django, django-models, chat

I want to get all messages belongs to an Inbox between user A and B.

My Models.

```
class Inbox(models.Model):
      by_user = models.ForeignKey(User); # who starts messaging
      to_user = models.ForeignKey(User); # second user

class Message(models.Model):
      sender = models.ForeignKey(User); # who starts messaging
      receiver = models.ForeignKey(User); # second user
      inbox = models.ForeignKey(Inbox); # message belongs to the inbox
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^chat/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.getMessages)
```

view.py

```
def getMessages(request, username):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    # get the inbox related to the request.user and user
    inbox = Inbox.objects.get('Whats will I write here');
    messages = inbox.messages.all().order_by('-date')
    return render(request, "inbox/chatBox.html", {'messages': messages})
```

Someone, please help me out to correct my urls.py and view.py.

Comment: Cool. What do you have so far? What problems are you having?

Comment: I have made Models. `Inbox and Message`. After that, I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the pattern on your URL.

Right now you have the start of the name, but no regex.

Follow the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) to adjust the urls.py to include the proper regex pattern.

---

It looks like your view and the URL won't end up answering your question of  getting all messages between A - B. At best, you could get all messages from A or all messages to B.  Since you have the sender/receiver on the message, you could just change the view to:

```
def getMessages(request, username):
  user = User.objects.get(username=username)
  messages = Messages.objects.filter(sender=user).order_by('-date')
  return render(request, "inbox/chatBox.html", {'messages': messages})
```

this would end up giving you all the messages sent by the user in the URL.

Comment: urls.py updated. Can you please help me out in views.py?

Comment: Updated answer to assist on views.py